# Elevation in material card not showing

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-fragments, android-elevation

I created a project in Android Studio implementing view binding and data binding. I don't know why material cards don't show elevation. I already added the declaration `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in my manifest file.
The material card is inside my fragment which is hosted by my activity... I think I made an error inflating tha fragment inside my activity, is it possible?

here is my fragment .xml file which contains the card:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".view.auth.LoginFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="24dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_sm"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                
                <!-- other components -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

As I stated above I already added the declaration hardwareAccelerated=true in my manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using  `android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_lg"`  use `app:cardElevation` .

```html
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation_lg"
    ...>
    <!-- Other attributes -->
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```